# Unwanted authentication request window at login after upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, login, evolution

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10 (64bit) on my Dell Laptop. Since then, at each login, a dialog window entitled `Mail authentication request ... Please enter the password for account ...@gmail.com` appears. I neither have any idea why my password (I checked it a hundred times) does not work ("`Password was incorrect`") nor why this dialog is displayed at all. As said, I never saw it before 13.10. I looked around in different forums and it seems (please correct me if I am wrong) that it stems from evolution server. I also deleted `~/.config/evolution/` entirely - without any effect. Further note that I am not using evolution at all and I would rather like to get rid of it completely, but I do not dare to remove evolution-server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I experienced a similar issue that was related to a Google account found under online accounts. I believe it was related to searching Google Docs in the dash.

You might want to look at the answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207337/access-prompt-keeps-asking-for-password), which yours seems to duplicate.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint to the other thread! It helped me to find the bug report [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcr/+bug/1044549/). I finally deleted `~/.config/goa-1.0/accounts.conf` which fortunately resolved the problem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 8):

`rm ~/.config/goa-1.0/accounts.conf` didn't do it for me, but `rm -rf ~/.config/evolution .local/share/evolution/` did. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Your "Password was incorrect" problem is because GMail identifies Evolution as a less secure app, so doesn't provide authentication to the app.
You can change this feature if you want, see Google's documentation on [less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps).

But if you don't want to allow your email access to evolution, you can remove your gmail account in evolution by following these steps

1. Open "Evolution"
2. Edit
3. Preferences
4. Select your email account, then press "delete"

This should remove your email account from evolution and no more signing in troubles anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the account from Online Accounts in settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - pop-up window asking me for the password for "personal" account. I didn't even know what 'personal' account. What helped me was removing evolution folder from /home/.config `rm -rf ~/.config/evolution` or using gui - go to files>preferences>views and make sure the box `show hidden and back up files` is tick then navigate to /home/.config where you can locate and delete your evolution folder. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I opened Settings and the menu Online accounts and noticed that there was a message about expired credentials. Clicking that displayed a login for my google account and after inserting those the request is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The problem was that evolution had an old password for Gmail. When I opened evolution, I got the same message, but put my proper gmail password in and saved it to the key-ring. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that this issue for me was resolved by removing the Firewall Configuration application.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend expanding this answer (by editing) to explain how you removed that application. Thanks!