# About Mail `Authentication Request`?

Tags: dpkg, authentication, evolution, keyrings, sendmail

I've installed Evolution, after that I've opened it, from that on-wards still I'm getting the mail **Authentication Request** as given below,

[image: Mail Authentication Request]

I've uninstalled Evolution though,still at each time of login I'm facing this.

How to fix this & is it because of Evolution or___ ?

How to know Evolution was completely uninstalled, if not, how to clear all the files of Evolution ?

Comment: Do you have 2-Factor Authentication or some other security setting enabled on your account?

Comment: You mean in Mail or my PC @Whaaaaaat

Comment: Your Gmail account.

Comment: No, It is in Disable mode @Whaaaaaat

Comment: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754?hl=en

Comment: But i have to disable the Authentication Request and I do not need to import or to connect via that request to my Mail-ID @Whaaaaaat

Comment: Possibly related to [*Access Prompt keeps asking for GMail password*](http://askubuntu.com/q/207337/448153) or [*Unwanted authentication request window at login after upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10*](http://askubuntu.com/q/368468/448153).