# Ubuntu keeps asking me for Gmail passworld

Tags: gnome, password, security, authentication

I'm using Ubuntu 15 and everything was fine till i decided to use evolution. Evolution failed to connect to Gmail and since then it asks me to enter my password for my Google account. according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207337/access-prompt-keeps-asking-for-gmail-password) post Iv deleted evolution, empathy, seahorse and everything that I thought would need to connect to my online accounts. But yet when I press windows key, The same message shows again and asks me for my Gmail password. Here is the message: 
[image]

This problem is driving me mad. Every time that I try to open something it shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you just have to tell Google that you are using a "[less secure app](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)" (i.e. an app that they don't recognize).

Comment: the problem is that I don't know which program is causing this problem. I have deleted evolution, empathy and all programs that seems to need an access to my Gmail account.

Comment: I'm not an expert on Gnome (I use Unity), but what about the calendar? Did you remove the account from "Online Account" before removing evolution and such? Might it be caused directly by `gir1.2-goa` (Gnome Online Account)?

Comment: I have deleted evolution from my calender and I have disabled automatic date & time. And There is no online accounts on my 'Gnome Online Accounts'

Comment: Try to delete ~/.config/goa-1.0/accounts.conf (or something equivalent)

Comment: I deleted both the goa folder and evolution folder, I don't know which one caused the problem, But now its fixed. Thank you